# VLC compilation fails on Mac with linking errors

Tags: linker, libvlc

I am trying to compile VLC like thus:

Download `git clone https://github.com/videolan/vlc.git vlc.git`

Build (as per https://wiki.videolan.org/OSXCompile/#Build_steps)

```
mkdir build && cd build
../extras/package/macosx/build.sh
```

which fails midway with the following error

```
make  all-am
  CCLD     libsvg_plugin.la
ld: warning: could not create compact unwind for _ffi_call_unix64: does not use RBP or RSP based frame
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_FSFindFolder", referenced from:
      _find_folder in libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o)
  "_kCFAllocatorSystemDefault", referenced from:
      _find_folder in libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o)
  "_CFURLCreateFromFSRef", referenced from:
      _find_folder in libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o)
  "_CFURLCopyFileSystemPath", referenced from:
      _find_folder in libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o)
  "_CFStringGetCStringPtr", referenced from:
      _find_folder in libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o)
  "_CFStringGetLength", referenced from:
      _find_folder in libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o)
  "_CFStringGetCString", referenced from:
      _find_folder in libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o)
  "_CFRelease", referenced from:
      _find_folder in libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[5]: *** [libsvg_plugin.la] Error 1
make[4]: *** [all] Error 2
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Which libs are missing? And how do I add them to the build process?

**Edit:**
I am on Mac 10.7.5.

Comment: What system are you on? Did you do the configuration steps first?

Comment: I am on 10.7.5. The script `build.sh` is supposed to run the configuration steps internally with default options which is what I used first. I had also tried the configuration `../extras/package/macosx/configure.sh --enable-debug --host=x86_64-apple-darwin10 --build=x86_64-apple-darwin10 --with-libiconv-prefix=/path/to/libiconvprefix --disable-addonmanagermodules` but that leads to the same linking error